# WSO2 IS "Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getDecision" for PolicySet

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, wso2-identity-server

I've been playing for some time with WSO2 and started testing PolicySets. I have a basic one that has a target for 'administrator' user role and a Policy that does nothing but Permit the access.

When I make a request I get `Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getDecision` as a response. I am not a Java programmer, so the stack trace is not very useful.

Am I doing something wrong, or there's a bug in WSO2?

The PolicySet:

```
<xacml3:PolicySet xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicySetId="admins" PolicyCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides" Version="1.0">
   <xacml3:Description></xacml3:Description>
   <xacml3:PolicySetDefaults>
      <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116</xacml3:XPathVersion>
   </xacml3:PolicySetDefaults>
   <xacml3:Target>
      <xacml3:AnyOf>
         <xacml3:AllOf>
            <xacml3:Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">administrator</xacml3:AttributeValue>
               <xacml3:AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:subject:role" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" MustBePresent="false"></xacml3:AttributeDesignator>
            </xacml3:Match>
         </xacml3:AllOf>
      </xacml3:AnyOf>
   </xacml3:Target>
   <xacml3:Policy PolicyId="admins.AccessGranted" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides" Version="1.0">
      <xacml3:Description></xacml3:Description>
      <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
         <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116</xacml3:XPathVersion>
      </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
      <xacml3:Target></xacml3:Target>
      <xacml3:Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="admins.AccessGranted.Access">
         <xacml3:Description></xacml3:Description>
         <xacml3:Target></xacml3:Target>
      </xacml3:Rule>
   </xacml3:Policy>
</xacml3:PolicySet>
```

The request:

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="true">
  <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">1773</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
  </Attributes>
  <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">view</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
  </Attributes>
  <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">115</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
  </Attributes>
</Request>
```

Please note that the user role is determined by making a request to a PIP.

Stacktrace:

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-28 09:04:20,438]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler} -  Illegal access attempt at [2015-10-28 09:04:20,0438] from IP address 192.168.1.112 while trying to authenticate access to service EntitlementService {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-28 09:04:20,558]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2015-10-28 09:04:20,557+0100] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-28 09:04:20,562] DEBUG {org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.JDBCAttributeFinder} -  The SQL query: select auth_group.name from AUTH_GROUP, AUTH_USER_GROUPS where auth_user_groups.group_id = auth_group.id and auth_user_groups.user_id = 1773 {org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.JDBCAttributeFinder}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-28 09:04:20,563]  INFO {org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.JDBCAttributeFinder} -  Before connecting {org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.JDBCAttributeFinder}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-28 09:04:20,645]  INFO {org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.JDBCAttributeFinder} -  Trying to connect!!! {org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.JDBCAttributeFinder}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-28 09:04:20,645]  INFO {org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.JDBCAttributeFinder} -  Connected. Executing Query {org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.JDBCAttributeFinder}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-28 09:04:20,726]  INFO {org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.JDBCAttributeFinder} -  Should have worked {org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.JDBCAttributeFinder}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-28 09:04:20,727] DEBUG {org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.JDBCAttributeFinder} -  [administrator] {org.xacmlinfo.xacml.pip.jdbc.JDBCAttributeFinder}
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-10-28 09:04:20,734] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} -  Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getDecision {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.<init>(Collections.java:1064)
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.iterator(Collections.java:1063)
        at org.wso2.balana.PDP.processPolicyReferences(PDP.java:329)
        at org.wso2.balana.PDP.processPolicyReferences(PDP.java:332)
        ....(1021 of at org.wso2.balana.PDP.processPolicyReferences(PDP.java:332) )
```

Comment: Do add the stack trace here

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with the Axiomatics Policy Server (see screenshot below) and I get:

- **NotApplicable** if I do not send the role
- **Permit** if I do send the role.

It seems like WSO2 IS probably fails to connect to your PIP and returns the exception. You'd have to look into your server logs. Alternatively give [Axiomatics](http://www.axiomatics.com/) a try.

[image: Axiomatics Policy Administration Point]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your configuration is valid, otherwise IS would alert it during publishing from PAP, but despite that - a runtime exception occurs.
This might happen when trying to run the PIP custom code or in the PIP runtime itself.

Check the IS server logs and make sure your PIP also write logs to it.

Comment: As far as I know it's not the PIP. There are other policies that use the same PIP for the exact same attribute and they don't fail this way. The difference is that they are Policies, not PolicySets.